# View http request when using mvn jetty:run

Tags: java, web-services, maven, http, jetty

Now, I run the simple example of Motown (Link [Single application setup](https://github.com/motown-io/motown/wiki/single-application-setup))

First, I check out code and install jar. After that, I run "mvn jetty:run". The application starts OK.

I want to review http request sending from browser into application but the console does not have this information. How can I view the http request?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use tcpmon - it is very simple tool, you just change port in the browser sending requests to tcpmon and tcpmon will send the requests to your application but also will print it. The same with responses. (https://code.google.com/p/tcpmon/)